Are descendent objects in SwiftData Models automatically deleted when set to nil?
Heads up: This is not a debugging question.  It is a theoretical/hypothetical question.  The code shown is to establish a mutual understanding.
In SwiftData (with SwiftUI), lets say we have:
@Model 
class Memo {

    // ...

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade)
    var recording: Recording?

    // ...

}

and
@Model
class Recording {
    // ...
}

The basic idea here is that the Memo "has a" Recording.
I am accessing the memos in the main app using
@Query private var memos: [Memos]

which is working fine.
I also understand how @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) works and it is working as expected with Recordings being deleted when a Memo is deleted.
*** BUT *** ...
If a Memo instance has a recording instance associated with it -- there is at least one Memo and one Recording object in the underlying database, if we do:
Memo.recoding = nil
Does this cause the underlying Recording object in the database to be deleted or does it remain as a dangling/orphaned object?

It remains in the database. Removing a relationship and removing an object are two different things

Seems like a valid answer
